# Creating and modifying pages with the REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

I would like to be able to modify and/or create pages dynamically using Power Automate flows. I assume I must use the SharePoint HTTP action, which interfaces with the SharePoint REST API.

There is very little information online about how to do this, so I wanted to ask if anyone here had experience with doing it. Secondly, how might I navigate the API to find the appropriate endpoints and request bodies?

Thank you for any help.